# IBM Watson Text to Speech credentials.HasIamTokenData() returning null everytime

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

```
credentials = new Credentials(tokenOptions, _serviceUrl);

        //  Wait for tokendata
        while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())
        {
            yield return null;

        }
```

`credentials.HasIamTokenData()` returns `null` everytime, when I use my application in `Hololens`, but it works perfectly fine in `Unity3D editor`.

I am not sure if I missed anything, which I need to particularly do for Hololens.

I passed empty `_serviceUrl` since it considers default one when noting is specified explicitly. Would it have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Service endpoint url should be declared. You can find the corresponding url for your service instance by its location:

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech/text-to-speech?code=unity#service-endpoint

Comment: But it works in Unity Editor. Shouldnt it work in Hololens as well?

Comment: We need to look at the code for Unity. I mean, you should have defined serviceurl somewhere in your code. Otherwise, it can not connect your service instance properly.